# How Properties can have Properties and Methods?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net

I am surprise to see that Properties can have further Properties and Methods. To better understand it lets take an example:

```
Panel1.Controls.Add();// Here Panel is object and Controls is Property and Add() is a Method.
Panel1.Controls.Count;// Here Panel is object and Controls is Property and Count is Property.
```

Can somebody explain it how we can create such a behavior in our classes
Thanks.

Comment: You should read further on Object Orientation I guess.

Comment: @jams an object of class may involve the properties which can again be an object of class so here controls is an object of ControlCollection class but we can not instantiate it directly rather .net controls which can be parent of other controls use this class to maintain a list of their children controls contained within parent controls

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's the back bone of object oriented programming.

The property can be a complex type that has it's own properties.

```
class Car{

    Engine CarEngine {get ; set; }
}
```

and

```
class Engine 
{
    int Cylinders {get; set; }
}
```

Here car has a property Engine. and Engine has it's own property. so if you have an instance of a car, you can do `myCar.CarEngine.Cylinders`

Answer (score 10):

`Controls` is a property which returns a `ControlCollection` - so your second statement works like this:

```
ControlCollection collection = Panel1.Controls;
int count = collection.Count;
```

Does that make more sense? It's not calling the next method / property on the property itself; it's calling it on the result of *evaluating* the property.

Answer (score 1):

Controls is a property of Panel1, but that property is an Object type, and any object can have properties and methods.